# Start javascript stopwatch from a specific dynamic value

Tags: javascript, dynamic, stopwatch

Before asking the question I would like to inform you that I've already searched in the questions with related topics , but my issues are different from others. Actually, I am building a "Javascript stopwatch", but there are some issues in the script that I've tried and searched to solve but can't find none. There are there issues in the stopwatch:

1. The stopwatch restarts automatically when page reloads even though the timer was stopped by the "stop_btn".
2. The stopwatch restarts automatically with the time comparing starting time and present time when page reloads; the paused time is totally ignored !
3. Can the stopwatch be started from a specific dynamic value; something like  PHP variable as:
   $time = "01:06:39"; ?

**The Javascript:**

```
var timer;
var startTime;
var isRunning = false;
var waitedTime = 0;
var stoppedTime = 0;

function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
  if (timer) {
    waitedTime += (Date.now() - stoppedTime);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  timer = setInterval(clockTick, 100);
}

function stop() {
  isRunning = false;
  clearInterval(timer);
  stoppedTime = Date.now();
}

function reset() {
  isRunning = false;
  stoppedTime = 0;
  waitedTime = 0;

  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = undefined;
  localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
  document.getElementById('display-area').innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}

function clockTick() {
  var currentTime = Date.now(),
    timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - startTime - waitedTime),
    hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
    mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
    secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
    ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
    display = document.getElementById("display-area");

  display.innerHTML =
    (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
    (mins > 9 ? mins : "0" + mins) + ":" +
    (secs > 9 ? secs : "0" + secs) + "." +
    (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};

var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop_btn');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('start_btn');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset_btn');

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stop();
});
startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  start();
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset();
})
start();
```

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this new variable and then use it in the start function. If the custom time is defined then localstorage or current date will be ignored.

```
var customStartTime = new Date() // enter your custom date in the Date() function.
```

Then modify the starttime in the start() function

```
startTime = customStartTime || parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using window.onload handler from which you can load stopwatch value  after page reload, I think this should cover first 2 issues you mentioned.
Also when you reload page stoppedTime variable will be 0, use localStorage to cache stoppedTime.

Comment: Yeah, that makes some sense ! Thank you.